# HTTP Post request with credentials and form in nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, http, object, request

I want to make an HTTP POST request to a server with credentials (username, password) and content.

More specifically, I used various approaches without success. One of them is:

```
var request = require('request');

request({
        url: 'https://path',
        method: 'POST',
        auth: {
               user: 'username',
               pass: 'password'
        },
        form: {
               'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
               'text' : 'input-text',
               'features': {
                      'score': true,
               }
        }
}, function(err, res) {
       console.log(res);
       var json = JSON.parse(res.body);
       console.log("Access Token:", json.access_token);
});
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: This depends entirely on the API of the server you're posting to.  Are they using basic auth?  Are you making a POST request to some kind of login function that will return a JSON token as you're callback suggests?  If it's an upstream server, you need to look at their docs and see what they're asking for.

Comment: Yes to both of your questions

Comment: Ok, then what do their docs say to do?

Comment: For example, in the "form" block of the above code, it has the "text"/"score"  I included above. However, I cannot get a response.

Comment: Can you provide a link to their documentation? You're not including enough information for anyone to help you as it stands right now.

Answer (score -1):

I feel more comfortable using promises. [request-promise documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise)

```
var request = require('request-promise');

var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: '',
    auth: {
        user: '',
        password: ''
    }, 
    headers: {
        '': '' 
    },

    json: true
}

return request(options)
.then(function (response) {
   // manipulate response
}).catch(function (err) {
    return err
})
```